# Fire button click in AngularJS

Tags: events, button, input, angularjs, click

I want to fire a button's click event when pressing ENTER inside a input and I find it quite difficult with AngularJS.

*My view (simplified, **updated**):*

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng:app="test">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="TestController">
        <button ng-click="onButton1Click()" class="btn1">Click Me</button>
        <button ng-click="onButton2Click()" class="btn2">Don't click me</button>
        <script src="lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="js/testcontroller.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

*My controller for this view:*

```
'use strict';

angular.module('test', [])
.controller('TestController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {

        $scope.onButton1Click = function() {
            alert("Hello");
        }

        $scope.onButton2Click = function() {
            $('.btn2').click();
        }
}])
```

I simplified all the code to this. When I click on **btn2** I get this error

> $apply already in progress

No, I can't call `$scope.onButton1Click()` directly, I must simulate the **btn1** click.

Comment: is app:click-watched="onButtonClick()" a custom directive you wrote?

Comment: Yes, it is a custom directive

Comment: can you put your code into a plunker?

Comment: I have added the directive's code

Comment: I simplified the code even more

Comment: Have you looked at the plunker solution given below? What is wrong with that solution and why is that not acceptable to you ? Between you should not be accessing the DOM from within a controller in Angular...

Comment: I will try it, it looks like the best idea for now, thanks

Comment: Be careful about using jQuery with Angular: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542/147601

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This took me a while to figure out (lots of fiddles).

`<form id="nowsorting" ng-submit="getData(sc_user)">Now sorting the Soundcloud likes of <input type="text" ng-model="sc_user"><input type="submit" value="Sort"></form>`

Make a form and use ng-submit to fire the event (likely a function).

Then create two inputs (one is "text" and the other "submit").

Then pushing enter should fire the ng-submit event/function.

Answer (score 13):

You mentioned

> fire a button's click event when pressing ENTER inside a input

So if it is safe to assume that you can have a form I would prefer using [ng-submit](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSubmit) as shown below.

```
<form ng-submit="clickEventFunction()">
  <input type="text"/>
  <button type="submit">Click</button>
</form>
```

Note button type should be **submit**.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you just have to call your $scope.onButtonClick()

Please check [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/atV0gglDvMMBXtxmVJMr)

```
$scope.onKeyPress = function($event) {
   if ($event.keyCode == 13) {
      $scope.onButtonClick();
   }
};
```

Comment: This doesn't really 'click' the button it just executes the same javascript code that is wired to the click of the button. it's slightly different since any additional listeners you have on that button click won't be triggered.