# AngularJS toggle button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a toggle button in Angular. What I have so far is:

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
     ng-click="toggleArchive(true)"
     ng-show="!patient.archived">Archive patient</a>
  <a class="btn btn-danger pull-right"
     ng-click="toggleArchive(false)"
     ng-show="patient.archived">Unarchive patient</a>
  .... some other buttons ....
</div>
```

Basically I achieve toggling, by having TWO buttons, and toggling between them. This is causing issues because the `ng-hide` just adds a `display:none` style to the button when it's hidden, which is causing me styling issues. Ideally I want to have ONE button, that has it's text, class and function call changed depending on the state of `patient.archived`.

What's a clean way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12008581/983992

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You should use [`ng-class`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass) to toggle between classes and bind the text with a regular [Angular expression](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression). Also, if your function `toggleArchive` only toggle the value, you can remove it and toggle the value from an Angular expression:

```html
<a class="btn pull-right" 
   ng-class="{true: 'btn-primary', false: 'btn-danger'}[!patient.archived]"
   ng-click="patient.archived = !patient.archived">
  {{!patient.archived && 'Archive' || 'Unarchive'}} patient
</a>
```

Comment: I considered this, and I realise it can be done, but it feels like their's a bit too much going on within the view that could be pushed onto a directive. Thoughts?

Comment: Directive is a good way to encapsulate reusable widgets. So if it's a common widget, or if you believe this is going to hit performance somehow, maybe it would worth a directive. Take a look here, where I share my thoughts about [when to write a directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15898991/when-to-write-a-directive/16121344#16121344).

Comment: Your logic is backwards. It's actually class: condition, not condition: class

Comment: That's actually not necessarily true @AndrewRhyne. You can use `condition: class` when you use it like a `Switch`, for example: `{'costumer': 'costumer-class', 'admin': 'admin-class'}[user.type]`. In the case above, I just wanted to avoid writing the condition twice (`!patient.archived` and `patient.archived`)

Answer (score 2):

It might help you:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
</head>

<body ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button ng-click="toggle()">Toggle</button>
    <p ng-show="visible">Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.visible = true;
  $scope.toggle = function() {
    $scope.visible = !$scope.visible;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for any other weary traveller...

you could simply have used `ng-if`. `ng-if` completely excludes the element from the DOM if false, so you'd have no issues with styles when not displayed. Also there is not really a need for the button group you could just change the text of the button

Something like this:

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
        ng-click="toggleArchive(true)"
        ng-if="!patient.archived">Archive patient</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger pull-right"
        ng-click="toggleArchive(false)"
        ng-if="patient.archived">Unarchive patient</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This may Help:

```html
<!-- Include Bootstrap-->
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.3.js"></script>

<!-- Code -->
<a href="#" ng-model="collapsed" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed">Click here to <strong>Toggle (show/hide)</strong> description</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest answer I've found.  I haven't tried it with animations because I just use it for quick setup.

```html
<a ng-click="scopeVar=scopeVar!=true">toggle</a>

<div ng-show="scopeVar">show stuff</div>
```

with `scopeVar=scopeVar!=true` undefined becomes true.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="toggle-button"
       ng-model="patient.archived">
```

Then style the checkbox like a button.

if the toggle needs to do more things, add the following to your patient class:

```js
class Patient {
  constructor() {
    this.archived = false;
  }
  ...
  get angularArchived() {
    return this.archived;
  }
  set angularArchived(value) {
    if (value !== this.archived) {
      toggleArchived(value);
    }
    this.archived = value;
  }
}
```

then use

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="toggle-button"
       ng-model="patient.angularArchived">
```