# Is it ok to use $controller inside a controller?

Tags: angularjs

I don't want to repeat the same code that I have in one of my controllers, so I have two options:

- use `$controller` service inside other controller to have some kind of inheritance
- use multiple `ng-controller` on the same `element` - but I don't know if this is possible?

What is the best solution to implement some kind of controllers inheritance ?

Comment: what do you want to do? normally you don't call one controller from another. it hurts your testing and doesn't look good for decoupling components. if there is some logic or data to be shared, you'd normally put that in a service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem in mixing controllers. You can't use `ng-controller` twice in the same element though, so you would need to inject `$controller` or create a directive that binds to the controller.

It doesn't make much sense to inject `$controller` inside the main controller of the element, instead, create a directive that is bound to the componentized controller, and this way, you will have componentized a behavior. Please refer to this answer [When to write a directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15898991/when-to-write-a-directive/16121344#16121344) to understand what I say.

Controllers are meant to control the `$scope`, and you don't have a way to extend the controllers. There is no problem in have multiple controllers changing a single scope and using it as a medium of communication between them.

Only use a service if you have a repetitive operation that you do not need a scope necessarily, just like fetching data, manipulating objects, calculating and etc.

Answer (score 5):

To quote [Angular Docs: Controller Inheritance Example](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.mvc.understanding_controller#controllerinheritanceexample):

> Controller inheritance in Angular is based on Scope inheritance.

In terms of the [example in the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.mvc.understanding_controller#controllerinheritanceexample), you could put your common methods on the `$scope` inside `ChildCtrl`, then those methods will automatically be available in the `$scope` inside `BabyCtrl`.

Although personally, I prefer adding common code into a service and injecting that service into multiple controllers.

Comment: I tried to put everything I could in to the services but I failed. The logic needs to have access to many variables on the scope.
I don't want to add additional `ng-controller` directive, as this would breake `setters` & `getters` - since I would have parent and child `$scope`. This would mean that I would not be able to do assignments on the child `$scope` and I'd have to write dozen of `setters` on the parent `$scope`. I am just curious if using `$controller` is a bad idea when all other things fail.

Comment: Can't you just pass all of the required variable values to the service method? Just because there are lots of values to pass doesn't mean that the service approach is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

You could also consider isolating the common functionality into a service.

Comment: I tried, but the logic is to complicated, needs to have access to many variables that are already on `$scope`